# How to add extra text in a next line in table cell

Tags: tables

My code is given below. Due to large text my table is crossing the page limit. I am trying to add next line in a cell for a text.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{Solution with \texttt{tabular}}
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll *{6}{c} @{}}
\toprule
Heading 1 & State of Health 
  &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Fasting Value} 
  &\multicolumn{3}{c}{After Eating}\\
\cmidrule(lr){3-5} \cmidrule(l){6-8}
 & &{Maxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}  &{Maxxxxxxxxxxxx} &{lllllllllllllllllLow}  &2hrs &3hrs &4hrs\\
%\makecell{Minnnnnn\\ nnnnnnnnnnn}
\midrule
add & Healthy  &70 &100 &a  &$< 140$ & &\\
\addlinespace %\midrule
del & Pre-Diabetes &101  &126  &a & 140--200 & &\\
\addlinespace %\midrule
mult & Diabetes &$>126$ &N/A  &a & $>200$ & &\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, you actually already have the solution with `\makecell`. You just need to load the eponymous package. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: an answer will be easier if you reveal what are the contents and whether there are any spaces in the contents which you are highlighting in red

Comment: @campa yeah already tried \makecell{Minnnnnn\\ nnnnnnnnnnn}dont know about package but getting error

Comment: @js bibra you can see the attached figure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have actually everything already there, and need only to load the `makecell` package.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}% <--- added

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{Solution with \texttt{tabular}}
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll *{6}{c} @{}}
\toprule
Heading 1 & State of Health 
  &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Fasting Value} 
  &\multicolumn{3}{c}{After Eating}\\
\cmidrule(lr){3-5} \cmidrule(l){6-8}
 & & \makecell{Maxxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} & Maxxxxxxxxxxxx & lllllllllllllllllLow & 2hrs & 3hrs & 4hrs\\
\midrule
add & Healthy  &70 &100 &a  &$< 140$ & &\\
\addlinespace %\midrule
del & Pre-Diabetes &101  &126  &a & 140--200 & &\\
\addlinespace %\midrule
mult & Diabetes &$>126$ &N/A  &a & $>200$ & &\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can write your own version, something like

```
\newcommand*{\mymakecell}[2][c]{\begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
```